# What is the IP of an elastic beanstalk instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created an EB instance which queries an Amazon Elasticsearch instance. Now I want to restrict access to my ES instance and allow only the EB instance access my ES. Therefore the question is how I can find the IP of the EB instance.

Comment: Isn't it located at the EC-2 Instance dashboard? If it is there, you must see an elastic ip attached on it.

Comment: @webmaster it wouldn't be an elastic IP, just a randomly assigned IP.

Comment: I currently got an EB instance which is for Java platform and got an automatically assigned elastic ip, maybe I set it on creation.

Comment: If it was automatically assigned, it is a random IP address. They don't allocate Elastic IPs automatically. If that was the case people using Elastic Beanstalk would very quickly run out of available Elastic IPs.

Comment: Yes random but it is located in the elastic ips section

Comment: @webmaster you did that yourself. Elastic IPs are never added to your account automatically. You only get 5 of them on your account unless you request more. Amazon explicitly discourages the usage of Elastic IPs.

Comment: Yeah ok clear, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk instances can be deleted and recreated automatically by Elastic Beanstalk. Further, Elastic Beanstalk can add servers to your environment automatically. When this occurs you have no control over the IP address that is assigned to your instance. As such, IP based security is not a good fit when you are using Elastic Beanstalk.

According to the [AWS Elastic Search service documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html#es-createdomain-configure-access-policies), there are three types of security policies you can use:

1. Resource-based access policy
2. IP-based policy
3. IAM user and role-based access policies

The third option is the best fit for Elastic Beanstalk. You can define an IAM role and specify that Elastic Beanstalk attaches that role to every server instance it created.

Comment: Thnx Mark, I guess I have to dive into IAM roles and resources..which honestly I m not familiar with.